# Calculating the width of a fixed div within an absolutely positioned div within a fixed element

Tags: html, css

Fixing a div within an absolutely positioned div within a fixed element...

HTML:

```
<aside class="dialogs">
    <div class="dialog">
        <div class="has-fixed-progress">
            <div class="dialog__body">…(other divs and content) ...</div>

            <div class="dialog-fixed-progress-wrapper">
                <div class="dialog-fixed-progress">
                    <button class="btn--primary">Attach designs</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Full codepen link: http://codepen.io/dmv912/pen/bgRQNB

I have a div .dialog-fixed-progress which you can see from the codepen link has a fixed position within an absolute div at the bottom of a fixed slideout menu to ensure it’s always at the bottom of the slideout even if the slideout has scrollable content (this works fine).

My issue is calculating and setting the correct width of the .dialog-fixed-progress to match the parent .dialogs or .dialog (either would work for me) taking into consideration all viewport widths (so resizing the browser) and the dialog scrollbar.

I can’t seem to calculate a correct percentage / or combination of pixels and percentage. Any help would be great!

(If possible I'd like a CSS/SASS only solution.)

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is what you meant this is why I will post it as a comment 'width:calc(50% - 17px)' The -17px is making sure it's not overlapping the scrollbar

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt Whilst that takes into consideration the scrollbar, the viewport changing is still the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `position: absolute` & `position: fixed` attributes as parent-child combo are rendered differently (and often weirdly) in different browsers, and should be avoided.

The following `position` attributes and `width` to elements should help you out.

```css
body {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dialogs {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation-duration: 0.16s;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.has-fixed-progress {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.dialog-fixed-progress-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dialog__body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.dialog-fixed-progress {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: right;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}
button {
  background: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside class="dialogs">
    <div class="dialog">
      <div class="has-fixed-progress">

        <div class="dialog__body">
          <p>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>…(other divs and content) ...
            <br/>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="dialog-fixed-progress-wrapper">
          <div class="dialog-fixed-progress">
            <button class="btn--primary">Attach designs</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm running your code snippet (in Chrome) I still get the same positioning issue of the .dialog-fixed-progress div where the button gets get off at different viewports (after reducing the width so that the scrollbar isn't overlaying the button)